# 'Echo' linux command is not working through Java Code

Tags: java, linux, jsch

I am trying to execute a simple linux command to append some text to a file in remote server through my java code. But it isn't working. When I run the same command in the linux box it works fine.

```
try {
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        Session sessionwrite = jsch.getSession(user2, host2, 22);
        sessionwrite.setPassword(password2);
        sessionwrite.setConfig(config);
        sessionwrite.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        Channel channel = sessionwrite.openChannel("exec");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                channel.getInputStream()));

        String command = "echo \"hello\" >> welcome.txt";
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
        System.out.println("done");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working?  Where do you think `welcome.txt` would end up being?  Have you tried using a `shell` channel?

Answer (score 0):

```
Channel channel = sessionwrite.openChannel("exec");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        channel.getInputStream()));

String command = "echo \"hello\" >> welcome.txt";
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
System.out.println("done");
```

You're missing the call to [`channel.connect()`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#connect()). `connect()` is the method which actually sends the request to the remote server to invoke the command. You should also call [`channel.disconnect()`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#disconnect()) when finished with the channel to terminate it. Your code might look something like this:

```
Channel channel = sessionwrite.openChannel("exec");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        channel.getInputStream()));

String command = "echo \"hello\" >> welcome.txt";
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
channel.connect();
channel.disconnect();
System.out.println("done");
```

I'll add that, in this particular example, there's no reason to open an input stream on the exec channel's standard input, so you could leave that line out.